# Prevent bourbon/refill sliding menu from operating at a specific breakpoint with js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bourbon

I am using [bourbon refill's](http://refills.bourbon.io/) sliding menu for a project and simply want it to operate until a particular break point. I figured this method below would work.

CSS:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  //sliding menu code
 }
```

Strangely, this works as the browser expands outwards. However when collapsing, there is a flash and the menu becomes visible for a second or two right before the breakpoint is reached. Should I be setting `js-menu` and the `sliding-menu-content` classes in the nav to `display:none` ?

**UPDATE:**
I added a conditional in the js to explicitly hide the classes which are showing...
but this removed the nav from my page when it was above 960px.
Also is this the correct way to control viewports with js/jQuery?

```
    var slidingElements = $('nav.js-menu.sliding-menu-content.is-visible, .sliding-menu-content');
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() >= 959) {
            $(slidingElements).hide();
        } else {
            $(slidingElements).show();
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.js-menu-trigger').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
        $('.js-menu').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $('.js-menu-screen').toggleClass('is-visible');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.js-menu-screen').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
        $('.js-menu').toggleClass('is-visible');
        $('.js-menu-screen').toggleClass('is-visible');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

I am aware of [breakpoints](https://github.com/xoxco/breakpoints) and other controllers (respond.js etc.). Is this the right way to tackle this?